# Showing two paths in $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus {(0,0)}$ are not homotopic.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm just starting, and am familiar with some very basic homotopy theory ($\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, Van-Kampen Theorem, the lifting lemma), but I can't seem to find a way to solve the following problem since it doesn't involve loops.

Consider two paths given by the left and right arcs of a circle around the origin,

$$p(t) = (\cos(t),\sin(t))\; \text{ and } \;q(t) = (\cos(t),-\sin(t))\;\text{ for }\;t\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2).$$

We have $\:p(-\pi/2) = q(\pi/2)\:$ and $\:p(\pi/2) = q(\pi/2),\:$ so they share the same endpoints but I have no idea how to show that these are not homotopic in $\;\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus {(0,0)}$.

Any help would be appreciated, particularly hints over complete answers. This is not homework.

Comment: Hint: If $p$ is path-homotopic to $q$, then $p \overline{q}$ is path-homotopic to the constant loop. Here $\overline{q}$ is $q$ traversed backwards. See a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a $1$-form 
$$\omega= -\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2} dx +\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} dy$$ 
and calculate $\int_p \omega$ and $\int_q \omega$. If $p$ and $q$ were homotopic with fixed ends then the integrals would be the same, because $\omega$ is a closed form ($d \omega =0$).

Comment: This suffices for this example, but if the paths are not smooth, I may not be able to define a smooth 1-form in this way.. is there a more general method?

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer though

Comment: @Nico: In general  they will be homotopic to some other smooth paths. This is an alternate method. Otherwise, you use the observation of Mr Chip and check that a path is not homotopic to a constant path,so reduce to loops. Then it's down to $\pi_1$.